# process id and command

Tags: shell, command-line, process, ps

I want to write the process id and command of all processes with some name and from some user (for example `root` and `init`).

What should I do?

```
ps -f -u root -C init
```

or

```
ps -f -U root -C init
```

writes more then just init the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the process ids, why not use `pgrep`:

```
pgrep -u root init
```

Or:

```
pgrep -U root init
```

Which switch you use (`-u`/`-U`) depends on what you want. The difference is, `-u` matches the effective uid and `-U` the real uid:

- The **effective** uid describes the user whose file access permissions are used by the process.
- The **real** uid is from the user who created the process.

**Edit:** to list the name too, add `-l`

```
$ pgrep -l -u root init
1 init
```

Comment: I want command too, can you do that with pgrep?

Comment: @TedGar yes add `-l` to the parameters